# What is a 3 Year (Indian) Engg. Diploma equivalent to UK education standards(HNC, HND or other)?

Tags: career-path, undergraduate, united-kingdom, international, india

Can anybody assist me in knowing what is a 3 year engg. diploma is equivalent according to UK education system or ECTS?

or

Is it equivalent to HND or HNC?

Comment: It usually depends on the awarding institution.

Comment: And how it is regarded by the institution applied TO...

Answer (score 1):

it is equivalent to RQF Level 3 (BTECH NATIONAL DIPLOMA/EXTENDED DIPLOMA)